# How can I model mutation and crossover for real valued encoding with discrete search space in Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, mutation, evolutionary-algorithm, crossover

I have P number of vectors of n dimensions each, where n is real valued. I want to find the best vector out of P using the fitness function Z(P). I am not being able to think of the modelling of the mutation and crossover methods, which would result in valid offsprings (within P). How should I perform the crossover and mutation in this scenario ?

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of refernences on how to cross/mutate a vector for a GA.  If you can figure it out in the 1-dim case, you can certainly do in for arbitrary dimensions.  Give it a go.

Comment: Dimension is not the problem. Thing is after crossover or mutation, I have to produce offspring that is present in the search space. My search space is discrete.